# org-babel python :session names matter

Tags: org-babel, python

For example, I get

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :session sdfjkl :results output
  import numpy
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: Python 3.8.0 (default, Oct 23 2019, 18:51:26) 
: [GCC 9.2.0] on linux
: Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

#+BEGIN_SRC python :session main :results output
  import numpy
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 152, in <module>
    from . import random
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/random/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    from . import _pickle
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/random/_pickle.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .mtrand import RandomState
  File "_bit_generator.pxd", line 14, in init numpy.random.mtrand
  File "_bit_generator.pyx", line 255, in init numpy.random._bit_generator
AttributeError: type object 'numpy.random._bit_generator.SeedSequence' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
#+end_example
```

Somehow, setting the name of the session to be `main` changes something
that makes things not work. Why is this?